# Counting sides or edges of polygon using open source GIS?

Tags: polygon, fields-attributes, open-source-gis, voronoi-thiessen

I wondered if it is possible to determine the number of sides / edges (not vertices) that a polygon has. Imagine the following case. There is a shapefile with 10 polygons.

Is there any way to determine for each polygon, how many sides there are and then write these into the attribute table?

I would be happy for any solution using open source tools.

In addition, I aim to use that in for describing voronoi polyons.

Comment: if the polygon has no hole, it is simply number of vertices -1

Comment: The general form of that formula is `nsides = nverts - nrings` (works for both single and multi-part polygons, with and without holes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS if your polygons do not have any holes or multi-parts:

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
for f in l.getFeatures():
    print f['NAME']
    print 'no. edges: %d' %(len(f.geometry().asPolygon()[0])-1)
```

replace 'NAME' with some identifier in your layer attribute table.

Concerning writing to the attribute table check the instructions in the [PyQGIS Cookbook - Modifying Vector Layers](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers).

Answer (score 6):

With Python and [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html), Polygons and MutiPolygons (multi-parts) are different geometries:

1) multi-parts geometries

```py
 import fiona
 shape = fiona.open("polygons.shp")
 # shapefile schema
 print c.schema
 {'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 'int:10')])}
 # first feature
 first = shape.next()
 print first (GeoJSON format)
 {'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1)])}


 multi = fiona.open("multipolygons.shp")
 print c.schema
 {'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 'int:10')])}
 # first feature
 first = shape.next()
 print first
 {'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]], [[(246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409), (246139.44557751188, 1000460.7859182726), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246189.03795626713, 1000403.5639427857), (246086.03840039085, 1000132.7132588148), (245990.66844124615, 1000205.1944277647), (246082.22360202507, 1000453.1563215409)]]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1)])}
```

2) With simple Polygons, the coordinates are

```py
coord = first['geometry']['coordinates']
[[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]
print len(coord)
1 # -> one polygon
```

And the equivalent LinearRing coordinates:

```py
linearR = coor[0] # or coord = first['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
print linearR
[(244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936), (244827.15493968062, 1000373.0455558595), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244933.96929392271, 1000353.9715640305), (244930.15449555693, 1000147.9724522779), (244697.45179524383, 1000159.4168473752), (244697.45179524383, 1000369.2307574936)]
```

So

```py
nb_vertices = len(lineaR) #(x,y) points
print nb_vertices
7 
nb_edges = nb_vertices -1
print nb_edges
6
```

3) With MultiPolygons, use a for loop

4) If the Polygons have holes, use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) with Fiona

```py
holes = fiona.open("poly_holes.shp")
from shapely.geometry import shape
# First feature
first = holes.next()
print first['geometry']['coordinates']
# conversion to shapely geometry
shape = first['geometry']
[[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 7.0), (7.0, 7.0), (7.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)], [(2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0), (2.0, 5.0), (2.0, 3.0)], [(5.0, 5.0), (6.0, 5.0), (6.0, 6.0), (5.0, 6.0), (5.0, 5.0)]]
# exterior coordinates
print list(shape.exterior.coords) # = LinearRing
[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 7.0), (7.0, 7.0), (7.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)]
edges_ext= len(list(shape.exterior.coords))
print edges_ext
5
```

Same with interior coordinates (look at the [Shapely manual](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html))

Comment: Thank you for pointing at Fiona and Shapely, I did not know either of them. Will check it out later today.

Comment: Okay, I finally got Fiona installed and running. Thank god. Then I reproduced your example code and got a python script running that showed - number of edges for the first polygon. I guess I have to loop through all other polygons, yet I have no idea how. Hence, the accepted answer goes to underdark - tadaaa.

Comment: Why tadaaa ? It is not a competition. If you are more comfortable with PyQGIS, use the underdark solution. If you want to use only Python, you need to learn first how to use Fiona and shapely.

Comment: Sorry for the tadaaa. I was actually  pretty happy to get the python setup finally running and will definitely continue with python only solutions. Thx again

Answer (score 1):

I finally found also an R-solution for my problem. The `rgeos` package offers the `get.pts` function which allows to extract the number of vertices. As we have learned from the first comments, the number of edges is equal to the number of vertices - 1. Programming a solution for my task in R seems now much easier.

Comment: Rgeos use the [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library, as [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) with `len(list(shape.exterior.coords)`(= get.pts), [PyQGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html), [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/), [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) and others...

Comment: Yep, that's how I found rgeos.